# Google Tag Manager snippet code automatically removed j.src

Tags: javascript, php, magento2, google-tag-manager, gtag.js

We are using the Magento 2 website we added a GTM snippet code but when we check in the "view page source" the j.src value shows nothing.

It should show **j.src='//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;**

but it is showing nothing **j.src='';**

This is the code -

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XYZ');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: _"Because of this, we are getting direct traffic in the GA4 account."_ - then you must have embedded GA a different way, I suppose, outside of GTM? Because with an _empty_ src attribute, this should not be able to load the GTM script at all.

Comment: @CBroe I edited my question, The URL is not showing in j.src, and the same thing j.src is showing in the development site.

Comment: Perhaps you got some sort of script blocker running on the production site, one of those consent banners asking users to allow tracking?

Comment: @CBroe do you know which things are blocking to show the "j.src" value? like mod_security or from this things are blocking from Cloudflare